# Unity touch event for Sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am try to check for a touch event for a `Sprite` but can only get this code to work on UI elements. I have seen examples for mouse events but I want to capture both mouse and touch because this game will be multi platform

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("play");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your spirte needs to have some `Collider`, there has to be a `PhysicsRaycaster` attached to the Camera (or the respective 2D equvialents if its a 2D game) and finally there ofc needs to be an `EventSystem`.

Answer (score 5):

To use `IPointerDownHandler` with non-UI elements requires you to add a collider to the Sprite and `PhysicsRaycaster` to the Camera.

Alternatively adding a collider and using [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) and [`OnMouseUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) work fine on mobile, as long as you only are interested in a single touch - which you likely are. Unity doesn't recommend using this due to "performance issues" - but I don't believe these performance issues are very significant, at least for most projects. There's a chance that if you have many objects with these callbacks on you may have issues on low-end devices, but I've never encountered this on projects dating back to the iPhone 3GS.

The alternative is to use the `Input.touches` array to check to see if touches are within your sprite. This requires a bit more work - so I'd suggest starting with OnMouseDown and see how you get on.

Comment: Sorry, I tried `OnMouseDown` but still no response. I think that is also only for GUI elements

Comment: These functions only work if there is a collider attached to the object, so make sure you have a collider

Comment: `IPointerDownHandler is only for UI input so can't be used with Sprites.` Thats not true. The sprite needs a collider and you need to add a PhysicsRaycaster (or their respective 2D version) to the camera - ofc also an EventSystem-

Comment: @yes - thanks for that, I'd forgotten about that. I've amended my answer.